# Time complexity of these two while loops

Tags: time-complexity

```
x = 1;
while(x<n)
{
    x = x + n / 10;
    m = n*n
    y = n;
    while(m>y)
    {
        m=m-100;
        y=y+20;
    }
}
```

The way I solved it: we are adding to x 1/10 of n every time, so no matter how big n will be, the number of repitation we are doing is always 10.
The inner loop is from n to n^2, and each variable in it is increasing linearly, so the inner loop should be O(n)

and because the outer loop is O(1), we get O(n) for all of the function.
but the optional answers for the question are: O(n^2), O(n^3), O(n^4), O(nlogn)

What am I missing? thanks.

Comment: This is not true "so no matter how big n will be, the number of repitation we are doing is always 10"  because x is incremented with `n/10` so, if n=100, the loop only runs one time....

Comment: But the value of m doesn't increase linear by increasing n.  I think it's `O(n^2)`.  *(Since `O(n^2-n) just seems silly)*

Comment: @luuk I don't understand why the loop will run only one time if n = 100, It will still run 10 times no? x will be equal to 1 - 11 - 21 - ... - 91 - 101

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the outer loop runs a constant number of times (10), but your reasoning about the inner loop isn't all the way there. You say that there is a "linear increase" with each iteration of the inner loop , and if that were the case you would be correct that the whole function runs in O(n), but it's not. Try and figure it out from here, but if you're still stuck:

The inner loop has to make up the difference between n^2 and n in terms of the difference between m and y. That difference between m and y is reduced by a constant amount with each iteration: 120, not a linear amount. Therefore the inner loop runs (n^2 - n)/120 times. Multiplying the number of times the outer loop runs by the times the inner loop runs, we get:

```
O(10) * O((n^2 - n)/120) 
= O(1) * O(n^2) 
= O(n^2)
```

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, loop from n to n^2 is O(n^2) and not O(n)?

Comment: Right, because you only increase a constant amount each time. Imagine if your loop starts at n=1,000 and goes to n^2 = 1,000,000. In our example, the inner loop would have to bring m and y 999,000 closer together, 120 at a time (as m decrease by 100 and y increases by 20). That's about n^2/120 iterations, not O(n) iterations. It would only be O(n) if m and y got some fraction of n closer together each iteration. But n could be a billion, it's not tied to 120 at all.